# Use output of a CURL and fail if the output contains ERROR

Tags: bash, shell, quality-gate

I am using this below CURL statement:

```
curl -u $SONAR_TOKEN: https://$SONAR_SERVER/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=$SONAR_PROJECT_KEY\&pullRequest=$SONAR_PR_KEY
```

Output:
[image: Actual Output]

Using `IF` statement to pass/fail the above scenario.

```
if [ "$quality_gatesstatus" != "OK" ] && [ "$quality_gatesstatus" != "WARN" ]; then
echo "check sonar server and fix the issues: $quality_gatesstatus"
exit 1
else
echo "Sonar Quality gate succeeded!!!"  
fi
```

But either of the true/false condition it is only printing first echo statement and failing the job. So what is the mistake I am doing here, one more things I cannot use "jq".

Comment: Sorry I have missed out to say, I want to send output of CURL statement to a keyword(eg: $quality_gatesstatus) but how to send required output only.

Comment: How to you transform the JSON output into Bash variables ? Some magic is missing here.

Comment: Sorry that's far from clear. Please be more precise. Which part of the JSON is the "required output" ?

Comment: @Necklondon
Sorry I forgot to mention that, from the JSON the required output is `"status"` value i.e: `"status":"OK"` or `"status":"ERROR"`.  And transform the JSON output to the variable is I have some doubt, right now I using like this `quality_gatesstatus=$(curl -u $SONAR_TOKEN: https://$SONAR_SERVER/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=$SONAR_PROJECT_KEY\&pullRequest=$SONAR_PR_KEY)`

Comment: So the content of `quality_gatesstatus` is the whole JSON string, right ?

Comment: Yes correct!!!!

Comment: There are multiple "status" fields, which one is to be checked ?

Comment: Yes correct, there are multiple status fields as they are for different attributes inside the quality gate. So I need to check as a combined output the `"status"` should only have `OK` then it should pass, if any one of the `"status"` field is showing `ERROR` it should fail.

Comment: Finally we are getting to the question. Do you realize the amount of effort required by readers, just to UNDERSTAND what you need ?

Comment: Extremely sorry for that, I couldnot make you to understand. But please let me know is still I am missing anything for asking question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `jq` this should to the trick:

```
quality_gatesstatus=$(curl -u $SONAR_TOKEN: https://$SONAR_SERVER/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=$SONAR_PROJECT_KEY\&pullRequest=$SONAR_PR_KEY)
echo "$quality_gatesstatus" | grep '"status":"ERROR"' > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "check sonar server and fix the issues: $quality_gatesstatus"
    exit 1
else
    echo "Sonar Quality gate succeeded!!!"  
fi
```

Comment: `quality_gatesstatus=$(curl -u $SONAR_TOKEN: https://$SONAR_SERVER/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=$SONAR_PROJECT_KEY\&pullRequest=$SONAR_PR_KEY | grep '"status":"ERROR"' > /dev/null)


if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo OK
else
    echo FAIL
    exit 1
fi`   Just wanted to check the alignment and the statement is correct?

Comment: Actually, I want to print the whole json content also if the condition "Fails". I mean `"status":"ERROR"`

Comment: Yes, its working. Can we make the json output content as a alligned one. As of now its printing in a single line so if it comes in a multiple line it looks better.

Comment: Just add `| tr ',' '\n'` at the end of the echo command

Comment: Thanks alot, all my requirements are working properly with your provided solution.